# How to use XMLHttpRequest to download an HTML page in the background and extract a text element from it?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I want to make a Greasemonkey script that, while you are in URL_1, the script parses the whole HTML web page of URL_2 in the background in order to extract a text element from it.

To be specific, I want to download the whole page's HTML code (a *Rotten Tomatoes* page) in the background and store it in a variable and then use `getElementsByClassName[0]` in order to extract the text I want from the element with class name "critic_consensus".

I've found this in MDN: [HTML in XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/HTML_in_XMLHttpRequest) so, I ended up in this unfortunately non-working code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
  alert(this.responseXML.getElementsByClassName(critic_consensus)[0].innerHTML);
}
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/godfather/",true);
xhr.responseType = "document";
xhr.send();
```

It shows this error message when I run it in Firefox Scratchpad:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/godfather/.
>   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS.

PS. The reason why I don't use the Rotten Tomatoes API is that [they've removed the critics consensus from it](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/forum/read/184496).

Comment: What is not-working? What error do you get?

Comment: No error message inside Firefox's Scratchpad. 
After seeing Igor Barinov's reply, I checked the Firefox Web Console and that's where appears the error message he mentioned. I added the error message to my question.

Comment: I edited my answer with new idea, give it a try!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For cross-origin requests, where the fetched site has not helpfully set a permissive [CORS policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing), Greasemonkey provides [the `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` function](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest). (Most other userscript engines also provide this function.)

`GM_xmlhttpRequest` is expressly designed to allow cross-origin requests.

To get your target information create a `DOMParser` on the result.  Do not use jQuery methods as this will cause extraneous images, scripts and objects to load, slowing things down, or crashing the page.

Here's **a complete script** that illustrates the process:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Parse Ajax Response for specific nodes
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method: "GET",
    url:    "http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/godfather/",
    onload: function (response) {
        var parser  = new DOMParser ();
        /* IMPORTANT!
            1) For Chrome, see
            https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#DOMParser_HTML_extension_for_other_browsers
            for a work-around.

            2) jQuery.parseHTML() and similar are bad because it causes images, etc., to be loaded.
        */
        var doc         = parser.parseFromString (response.responseText, "text/html");
        var criticTxt   = doc.getElementsByClassName ("critic_consensus")[0].textContent;

        $("body").prepend ('<h1>' + criticTxt + '</h1>');
    },
    onerror: function (e) {
        console.error ('**** error ', e);
    },
    onabort: function (e) {
        console.error ('**** abort ', e);
    },
    ontimeout: function (e) {
        console.error ('**** timeout ', e);
    }
} );
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do this but in my responseText I have an isolated string as html response from the server, It look like this: `<!DOCTYPE html> \n<html> \n<head> \n    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n    <meta http-equiv=\"` and so on. How Can I get normal Html from this isolated string? Maybe some nice ways instead of replace or trim the string?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/godfather/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Because you are not the owner of the resource you can not set up this header.

What you can do is set up a proxy on heroku which will proxy all requests to rottentomatoes web site
Here is a small node.js proxy https://gist.github.com/igorbarinov/a970cdaf5fc9451f8d34

```
var https = require('https'),
    http  = require('http'),
    util  = require('util'),
    path  = require('path'),
    fs    = require('fs'),
    colors = require('colors'),
    url = require('url'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.load();

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
var host = "www.rottentomatoes.com";
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
    // You can define here your custom logic to handle the request
    // and then proxy the request.
    var path = url.parse(req.url, true).path;

    req.headers.host = host;
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: "http://"+host+path,

    });

}).listen(port);

proxy.on('proxyRes', function (res) {
    console.log('RAW Response from the target', JSON.stringify(res.headers, true, 2));
});


util.puts('Proxying to '+ host +'. Server'.blue + ' started '.green.bold + 'on port '.blue + port);
```

I modified https://github.com/massive/firebase-proxy/ code for this

I published proxy on http://peaceful-cove-8072.herokuapp.com/ and on http://peaceful-cove-8072.herokuapp.com/m/godfather you can test it

Here is a gist to test http://jsfiddle.net/uuw8nryy/

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
  alert(this.responseXML.getElementsByClassName(critic_consensus)[0]);
}
xhr.open("GET", "http://peaceful-cove-8072.herokuapp.com/m/godfather",true);
xhr.responseType = "document";
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I'd prefer not use a proxy for various reasons: inevitable slower page loading, permanent need of proxy,  etc.

Answer (score -1):

The JavaScript [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) prevents you from accessing content that belongs to a different domain.

The above reference also gives you four techniques for relaxing this rule (CORS being one of them).